# View to show node titles only when a new comment has been posted?

Tags: 7, views, comments

I am trying to create a view that will show the titles of all nodes only when these nodes have new comments. I need a filter like "Content has new comments" but there isn't any.
Can somebody help?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "new". Can you elaborate?

Comment: I mean comments that are not viewed yet. My view will be a list of node titles with new comments. When clicking on a node title the user will be directed to the full node page where all comments are attached (via an EVA field). The new comment will be the first comment of the entire comment list. Ideally i would like this comment to have a "new" mark which will disappear when the user leaves that node page. But this specifically is a different problem i haven't thought about yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a relation in views "comments of the node" and add filter criteria by comment post date. As I know there is no status "new" in comments that's why you can limit them by date.

Or you can add custom field with status but you will need a logic how to add and remove that status.